# Question about conservation( unchangingness ) of order of modular multiplicative cycle when cycle is multiplied by relatively prime number.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, multiplicative-order

I'm currently trying to learn about totient, while following the proof of the fermat's little theorem I got stuck at some part and that part include a question of title.

first, to prevent the confuse of word, I'll fix the meaning of specific word here.

order: the number of multiplication takes to circle around and get back to where it started at modular multiplicative cycle.

and for simplicity, 
I want further argue to be based on assumption that the modular multiplicative cycle I'll mention afterward will be 
multiple of a (mod m)

---

Although the question is already stated at title, 
Why the order of modular multiplicative cycle doesn't change when entire cycle is multiplied by number which is relatively prime to m

in other word, Why the order of modular multiplicative cycle changes when entire cycle is multiplied by number not relatively prime to m?

---

p.s. If you insist me specific part confusing to you, then i'll try my best to correct the word to be more based on definition and convention.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot understand what you are asking. Are you able to provide a formal statement (quantifiers and stuff) or an example, maybe?

Comment: @Mindlack The statement was
"If a is relatively prime to m, then repeated multiplication by a modulo m partitions the integers between 0 and m-1 that are relatively prime to m into cycles that are all the same length"
and for example, 
think about 3 repeated modular multiplication cycle.
you keep multiplying 3 to some number between 0 and m-1 until you get to where you started. (i'll express as a cycle by writing numbers inside curly braces.)

Comment: @Mindlack m= 16 anyway.. sry i miss edited.
so 3 multiplication with modulo 16 you get,
{1, 3, 9, 11}, {5, 15, 13, 7}, {2, 6}, {4, 12}, {10, 14}
Do you see that each numbers inside the curly braces order of 4? {1, 3, 9, 11}, {5, 15, 13, 7} those are all relatively prime to 16 and if you multiply any numbers among these braces to a entire brace, order doesn't change.
i.e. if you multiply 5 to {1, 3, 9, 11} order doesn't change you just get {5, 15, 13, 7}.
if you multiply 7 to {1, 3, 9, 11}, then {7, 5, 15, 13} which has identical element with {5, 15, 13, 7}.

Comment: @Mindlack On the other hand, if you multiply non-relatively prime number such as, 2 or 4 or 6 numbers that doesn't belong to curly braces of order 4, it's order diminishes.
i.e. multiply 2 to {1, 3, 9, 11} you get {2, 6} which order is now 2.

Answer (score 1):

A basic fact about cyclic groups is that $\mid g^k\mid=\frac n{(n,k)}$, where $n=\mid g\mid$.

Thus the order changes iff $k$ is not relatively prime to $n$.  (Of course,  this is multiplicative notation.  For additive notation, we get $\mid kg\mid=\frac n{(n,k)}$).

Comment: May I get a bit of explanation about notation you used for multiplicative cyclic groups? or some reference i should look at? I think your answer is what i was looking for.

Comment: In additive notation,  $+$ is used for the binary operation.   $ng=\underbrace{g+\dots+g}_{\text{n-times}}$;  whereas in multiplicative it's $g^n$.  Glad to have helped.

Comment: can you explain me what ∣g^k∣=n/(n,k) mean?               
is (n, k) meaning computation of combination? nCk?

Comment: Sure.   $(n,k)$ is the greatest common divisor (gcd) of $n$ and $k$.  So, it means the order of $g^k$ is the order of $g$ divided by the gcd of $n$ and $k$.